# Getting JSON data from server with Phonegap for BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, jsonp, cordova

I'm working on a BlackBerry application using phonegap. The problem is, it doesn't get an external JSON from my server on a real device, altough it works well on Ripple.

First, I've added `<access subdomains="true" uri="*" />` to the build.xml file.

This is my html/javascript code:

```
<script>
function onLoad() {
   $.ajax({
      type : 'GET',
      url : "http://myserver.com/api/test.php",
      jsonpCallback : 'jsonCallback',
      crossDomain : true,
      cache : false,
      dataType : "jsonp",
      jsonp: 'callback',
      success: function(json) {
         $( ".info" ).html("success");
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         $( ".info" ).html("Error: " + textStatus + ":" + errorThrown);
      }
});
}
</script>
<body onload="onLoad();">
...
</body>
```

When I run this on the Ripple emulator, the success callback is called, but on a real device (BlackBerry 7.0) I get this output:

> parsererror: json callback was not called.

As a side note, I have validated the response in JSONLint and it's ok. Also, the response is a valid jsonp response:

```
jsonCallback({"result":{"status":"ok","testText":"There goes my content"}});
```

Furthermore, I put code on my server to log access, and it's not being called, so I guess the problem is not my server code, but on the mobile code somewhere.

Comment: Read this https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/BVHbPTYIgag it might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a jsonp call, instead of it you better do a normal json call.
In your server side throw some php headers like this:

```
  <?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
  header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
  ?>
```

You'll be able to use all the jQuery AJAX callbacks.

Comment: But, i don't have other http origin. Remember: it's a blackberry application. It's not a website.

Comment: I've just updated the answer, using a wildcard will give you access from a mobile app. Please give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not using jsonp?

```
 $.ajax({
      type : 'GET',
      url : "http://myserver.com/api/test.php",
      dataType : "text",
      success: function(jsonText) {
         var json = $.parseJSON(jsonText);
         $( ".info" ).html("success");
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         $( ".info" ).html("Error: " + textStatus + ":" + errorThrown);
      }
```

And just in case, make sure your device has internet access before trying it!

**EDIT**

Have you tried what's explained on @GEMI's comment?

To access external sites from your you'll need to add the domain names to your app's white list.  This is done in the config.xml file:

```
<access subdomains="true" uri="http://my.domain.com" />
```

In addition, if you're using PhoneGap APIs or BlackBerry WebWorks 
APIs, you'll need to add the appropriate features under the domain:

```
<feature id="phonegap" required="true" version="0.9.3" />
```

Comment: It's still not working. It now displays: "Error requesting resource".

Comment: But is the request even reaching the server? Adding `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` to your `Response` on the server side should enable access from any origin so you don't get errors. Is your code reaching the `Success` or the `Error` callback on the ajax request?

Comment: NO. I added the header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); but it isn't even reaching the server. What could I still be missing?

Comment: You 100% sure your device has internet access? That should have at least reached the server. If you try in a different device, same thing happens?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... I solved it by setting expected contentType to my ajax call.

contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"

The skrip look like this in the end.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://myUrl.com/jsonFile.json.js",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) { // Response function
    //work with your data
  },
  error : function () {
     //Handle your errors
  }
});
```

My requested file is only a js file with json content like: [{"id":"1","name":"lol"}...]

Hope this helps someone :)